# Apache 2.2 VirtualHosts URL not found

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost, vhosts, virtual-hosts

I'm hoping you can help. I have an existing Apache 2.2 server which serves a website I maintain. I am attempting to add additional websites for a colleague. Having done so, I get the following when I attempt to access the URL:

> Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Here's a summary of my httpd-vhosts.conf file. I have three new, roughly identical, hosts that aren't working. Only NDV and the default are working.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost anycast.ns.cs.boeing.com:80>
        ServerName anycast.ns.cs.boeing.com
        ServerAdmin aodhan.hoffman@boeing.com
        DocumentRoot "/opt/www/anycast"

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin "/opt/www/anycast/cgi-bin/"
        ErrorLog "logs/grant_error_log"
        CustomLog "logs/grant_access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin aodhan.hoffman@boeing.com
        DocumentRoot "/opt/httpd/manual"
        ServerAlias ntpm-application-01.ns.cs.boeing.com
        ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
        CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin aodhan.hoffman@boeing.com
        DocumentRoot "/opt/www/ndv/html"
        ServerName ndv.web.boeing.com
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/opt/www/ndv/cgi-bin/"
        ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
        CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/opt/www/ndv/html/" >
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes 
        AddType text/html .shtml
        AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml 
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/opt/www/anycast/html/" >
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes 
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Based on the config above, this is what the server is seeing.

```
$ sudo bin/apachectl -S

VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server ntpm-application-01.ns.cs.boeing.com (/opt/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:30)
         port 80 namevhost ntpm-application-01.ns.cs.boeing.com (/opt/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:30)
         port 80 namevhost ndv.web.boeing.com (/opt/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:39)
         port 80 namevhost anycast.ns.cs.boeing.com (/opt/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:48)
         port 80 namevhost ntpget.ns.cs.boeing.com (/opt/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:60)
         port 80 namevhost dnsdig.ns.cs.boeing.com (/opt/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:70)
Syntax OK
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to mix configuration approaches:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the example from the Apache Docs regarding name based VHosts.

I can see in your config VirtualHost without the * -> anycast.ns.cs.boeing.com:80

as well as VHosts without a server name like ServerAlias ntpm-application-01.ns.cs.boeing.com
which has an alias, but no name.

I would start to even out the configurations like in the example and then try if the apache is more happy with that.

In short: Make sure each of you entries have *:80 and a server name.

Edit: This config is not tested but might work for you

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName anycast.ns.cs.boeing.com

        ServerAdmin aodhan.hoffman@boeing.com
        DocumentRoot "/opt/www/anycast/html"

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin "/opt/www/anycast/cgi-bin/"
        ErrorLog "logs/grant_error_log"
        CustomLog "logs/grant_access_log" common

        <Directory "/opt/www/anycast/html/" >
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes 
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>        
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ntpm-application-01.ns.cs.boeing.com

        ServerAdmin aodhan.hoffman@boeing.com
        DocumentRoot "/opt/httpd/manual"

        ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
        CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ndv.web.boeing.com

        ServerAdmin aodhan.hoffman@boeing.com
        DocumentRoot "/opt/www/ndv/html"

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/opt/www/ndv/cgi-bin/"
        ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
        CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

        <Directory "/opt/www/ndv/html/" >
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes 
            AddType text/html .shtml
            AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml 
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've evened out the config, it now looks like this but behaves no differently. ndv still works, but anycast simply returns 'URL not found'. Since I have indexes on I'd expect to see an auto-index, but instead it simply says '/' not found. It boggles.

Comment: Thanks, but behaves no differently. 

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName anycast.domain.com
        ServerAdmin aodhan.hoffman@domain.com
        DocumentRoot "/opt/www/anycast"
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin "/opt/www/anycast/cgi-bin/"
        ErrorLog "logs/grant_error_log"
        CustomLog "logs/grant_access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/opt/www/anycast/html/" >
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes 
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: Uhm, just something I notice. Do quotes really work in a apache config? I have never seen that.

Comment: I guess quotes are ok, as you config seems ok for the webserver. I attached a reformatted one, that might work out for you. Please be aware that your document roots and directoy directive were pointing to different directories . and ./html and I would advise you to incormporate the directory entries within the VHOSTs.

Comment: And just one additional word: unless this thing is purely intranet: order allow,deny -> allow from all can be a very insecure thing.

Answer (score 1):

My advise is to open and read all the logs that apache generates. That will give you a clue of where the problem lies. I read the log at `"/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"` in a mac and found my clue: `DocumentRoot [/path/to/rootdir] does not exist.`

I opened the vhost file and found out that instead of encapsulating the root directory in double quotes I had used other characters that seemed like double quotes. I replaced them by the real double quotes, restarted apache and then the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is uninstalling and upgrading (in my case Wampserver) the software that you're using.

Comment: Please improve your answer. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more information.